How does the function fork() work such that the "father" process creates 6 other processes?
in this code snippet:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    printf("i: %d\n",i);
    if(fork() | fork()) {
      fork();
    }
  }
}

the question is how many times the number 1 is printed to stdout, its 7, but i couldn't figure how and why ,like how does the function fork() work such that the "father" process creates 6 other processes?
I thought that the first fork created one other process(making 2 in total), and the second fork creates two other (making 4 in total), and then lastly the nested fork would create 4 other processes (making 8 in total), but that doesn't seem the case, and i think I'm messing something here.

The title should describe your specific question, not just state that you have one. Part of its purpose is so other people who find your question in search results for their own problem can tell if the answers you get will help them, so a good title is as descriptive as possible.

I would assume that only the first fork() in the if-condition is executed, as if it returns non-null, the second isn't evaluated, as the condition is already true.

It's using fork() | fork() not fork() || fork(). There's no short-circuit evaluation.

And OP, have you tried running this under strace -f -e trace=%process or similar? You can see exactly what it does...

@Thatoneguy –
Print getppid() and getpid() along with the number, and add while (wait(NULL) > 0) ; at the end of main, then you'll get a clearer picture.

@Useless Well spotted!

The second fork in fork() | fork() runs in both the parent process and the new child process.

The third fork() is in the body of a conditional statement.  You don't seem to be considering under which circumstances it is evaluated at all, and under which it isn't.

Suggest you this, pipe the output to a log file and take a look.
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    printf("parentPID:%d: myPID:%d i:%d\n", getppid(), getpid(), i );
    if(fork() | fork()) {
      fork();
    }
  }
}

